# Запуск скриптов через кастомный Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Возможно ли указать в package.json путь чем запускать js скрипты? 
Есть у меня NodeRun.exe, который должен запускать мои скрипты в корне проекта. 
Так же необходимо запускать npm через этот `кастомный` NodeRun.exe.

Comment: я видел в репаке игры Escape from Tarkov nodejs сервер, который реализован через "локальную ноду", погуглил ничего сладкого не нашел, если никто не ответит капай в сторону торрента с игрой)

Comment: @Vadim решил вопрос тем, что в корень проекта поместил node.exe (необходимо назвать ее именно node) и npm запускал именно эту ноду. Думаю что cmd вначале ищет исполняемую программу в папке вызова, а уже потом в PATH.